# Unable to update PageAdapter's TextView from a Timer

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a Timer in my onCreate(), it should set a new text when value when the `timeString` changes. Unfortunately right now it doesn't change at all.

Here is a snippet of my code. I don't know what I've missed? If you guys have any suggestion then please let me know.

**ViewPagerActivity**

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends MapActivity {
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private String timeString;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);

        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    timerMethod();
                }
            }, 0, 1000);
    }

    private void timerMethod() {
        this.runOnUiThread(doTimer);
    }

    private Runnable doTimer = new Runnable() {
            private int totalSecs;
            private int hours;
            private int minutes;
            private int seconds;

            public void run() {

                totalSecs += 1;
                hours = totalSecs / 3600;
                minutes = (totalSecs % 3600) / 60;
                seconds = totalSecs % 60;

                timeString = (String) (hours > 9 ? String.valueOf(hours): AddZero(hours)) + ":" +
                    (String) (minutes > 9 ? String.valueOf(minutes): AddZero(minutes)) + ":"
                    +  (String) (seconds > 9 ? String.valueOf(seconds): AddZero(seconds));

                //pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            private String AddZero(int text) {
                return "0"+ text;
            }
        };
}
```

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements TitleProvider {
    private final Context context;
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;
    private View view;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
    }

    private static String[] titles = new String[] { "Page1", "Map" };

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View pager, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (position == 0) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whereami, null);
            ((ViewPager) pager).addView(view, 0);
        //here, set text at first time when view was create only
        //and not update,when value of timeString change
        txtDurationValue = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtDurationValue);
        txtDurationValue.setText(timeString);

        }
        if (position == 1) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_map_activity, null);
            ((ViewPager) pager).addView(view, 0);
            mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);

            mapController = mapView.getController();
            mapController.setZoom(14);
        }

        return view;
    }

 public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
     return POSITION_NONE;
 }

}
```

Comment: What is `TimeRunning` set to?

Comment: actually 1 for starting..0 for stopping 2 for pausing. it like a flag (i will cut it out for this example) sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line:

```
txtDurationValue = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtDurationValue);
```

I'm assuming you have a `TextView txtDurationValue;` in your adapter which you haven't included in your question source code? If it isn't in there add this inside the adapter. (Technically you shouldn't expose raw values/views from the adapter, you should use get/sets but this should work until you refactor):

```
public TextView txtDurationValue;
```

You should then be able add

```
public void setText(String text) {
    txtDurationValue.setText(text);
}
```

Which will mean you can change this //pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); to:

```
((ViewPagerAdapter)pager.getAdapter()).setText(text);
```

What it doesn't do is take care of the fact that you're setting off a timer in onCreate() which is getting fired before the elements have been instantiated.

This is my favourite Android hack (you can use `indicator` or any other view which you have reference to. Doesn't really matter in this instance). It fires code directly after the view has been displayed:

```
    ViewTreeObserver vto = indicator .getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        public void run() {
                           timerMethod();
                        }
                    }, 0, 1000);
    });
```